# Accept ip connections from address and port with already established connections

Tags: networking, firewall, nftables

I have put in place a solution to open temporarily a port based on nft:

```
# create the nft set
nft add set ip filter SSHallowed { type ipv4_addr\; timeout 2m \;}

# add the rule to the table
nft insert rule ip filter INPUT ip saddr @SSHallowed tcp dport 22 accept

# to add ips to the set
nft add element ip filter SSHallowed { XX.XX.XX.XX }
```

Is there any way I can accept new connection, from the same ip and to the destination port of another already established connection, without having to run the "nft add element"? I think that should be something similar to

```
nft insert rule ip filter INPUT ct state related tcp dport 22
```

But that one has not worked.

Comment: Is the goal to allow additional ssh connections to a server after an initial port-knocking method (or any other method) was used to allow the initial ssh access? You should describe both the intended goal (to avoid any XY problem) and give an example. I can already tell to check SSH's ControlMaster option to probably avoid having to do all this.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing statuses.

Thinking about iptables, you would allow both related and established connections. Then, I would assume you're looking for something like this:

```
nft insert rule ip filter INPUT ct state related,established tcp dport 22
```

Comment: The reason because of I have not included the established, is because that established is already stated in another rule, table and protocol wide.